# What pars to eliminate margin in a `png file` for the following R plot?

Tags: r, function, plot, png

I was wondering given the R code for the plot below, how I can get a png file of this plot such that the plot fills all the image with **no** `margin` left?

What I have tried so far was playing with `mar` and `oma` with no success:

```
N = 20 ; df = N-1  
par(oma = rep(0, 4), mar = rep(0, 4))  

 png("plot.png", width = 4, height = 5, units = "in", res = 500)

BB = curve( dt(x*sqrt(N), df)*sqrt(N), -1, 1, n = 1e4, xlab = "d", 
                   ylab = NA, font = 2, font.lab = 2, type = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n", mgp = c(2, 1, -.5))

 polygon(BB, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, .4), border = NA)

 dev.off()
```

Comment: I suspect what you want is to add `xaxs="i", yaxs="i"` to your `curve` statement.

Comment: @G5W, but this changes the current shape of the plot! I want to keep the current shape and just get a high-quality png format of what is currently shown in the graphical device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the following worked for me with the help of one of the colleagues from SO:

```
 N = 20 ; df = N-1  
 par(oma = rep(0, 4), mar = c(2.5, .01, 0, .01), mgp = c(1.5, .3, 0), xpd = NA)  

  BB = curve( dt(x*sqrt(N), df)*sqrt(N), -1, 1, n = 1e4, xlab = "d", 
        ylab = NA, font = 2, font.lab = 4, type = "n", yaxt = "n", 
        bty = "n", cex.axis = .7, cex.lab = .9)

    polygon(BB, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, .4), border = NA)

    dev.copy(png, "plot.png", width = 2, height = 3, units = "in", res = 500)
    dev.off()
    dev.off()
```